# Suddenly fcm notification do not work on some of iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM notification had reached on all iOS devices. But notification came not to work on some of the devices which were registered about 1 year ago. FCM token and APNs token don't seem to change. Why didn't reach notification? Does FCM token have to expire?

**XCode 10.1, Firebase 5.20.1**

1.AppDelegate

````
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  ```
  Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
  ```
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
  ```
  Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
  ```
  ```
  //store fcmtoken and apnstoken
  ```
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
  ```
  //store fcmtoken and apnstoken
  ```
}
````

2.info.plist

```
FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = No
```

FCM token and APNs token don't change, But notification came not to reach on some of the devices which were installed about 1 year ago.

Comment: just update your certificates and provisioning profiles on Apple Account

Comment: Thank you very much. But I use authentication key. I don't use certificates, and I use provisioning profiles only for tests.
[Configuring APNs with FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug of FCM.
[#[19001]](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Cloud%20Messaging/19001)

It seems that  the problem was already solved.